# Error with dynamically resizing cell size

Tags: ios, swift

I try to resize the cell individually by employing the following code.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    var itemSize : CGSize?

    let currentCell = self.collectionView?.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! CustomCell
    let imageSize : CGSize = (currentCell.imageView?.image?.size)!
    let aspectRatio : CGFloat = imageSize.width / imageSize.height

    if aspectRatio > 1 {
        itemSize = CGSize(width: self.maxItemSize.width, height: maxItemSize.height / aspectRatio)
    }else{
       itemSize = CGSize(width: self.maxItemSize.width * aspectRatio, height: maxItemSize.height)
    }

    return itemSize!

}
```

But i always obtain fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value at this line

```
let currentCell = self.collectionView?.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! CustomCell
```

if i remove the block, then everything else works perfectly.. Anyone knows what is going on?

Thanks in advance.

Edited: Added CellForItemAt Function

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
    cell.backgroundColor = colorArray[indexPath.section]
    cell.imageView?.image = imageArray[indexPath.item]
    return cell
}
```

Comment: @ThomasG. Hey thanks very much for answering. You are right.. I tested out, the problem lies in down casting to customCell, but i still do not know what is wrong. I have provided CellForItemAt function in the edited part. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sizeForItemAt()` gets called before `cellForItemAt()`, so you are trying to grab information from the cell (its image size) but the cell hasn't been created yet.

I see that on your `cellForItemAt()` you use an array for the images, consider using the same array in `sizeForItemAt()` to grab the image size, for example the beginning of your `size` func could look like;

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    var itemSize : CGSize?

    // delete this line** let currentCell = self.collectionView?.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! CustomCell
    // let imageSize : CGSize = (currentCell.imageView?.image?.size)!
    let imageSize : CGSize = imageArray[indexPath.item].size // or indexPath.row depending on your structure
    let aspectRatio : CGFloat = imageSize.width / imageSize.height
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, actually i just did that haha.. Was thinking what was wrong anyway.. But you gave a really good answer.. Thank you! (: